# Java String split with regular expression and escape character

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split a string in below condition.

1. Split with `/` and should not split if it has `\/`.
2. Split with `=` and should not split if it has `\=`.

Basically looking for **TWO** regular expressions which split with above conditions and avoid if it has escape character.

Comment: Guys thanks for the answers to wind up i have used below regex for my solutions.
REGEX_FORWARD_SLASH_WITH_NO_SLASH_PREFIX = "(?<!\\\\)/"
REGEX_EQUAL_TO_WITH_NO_SLASH_PREFIX = "(?<!\\\\)="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using lookarounds here:

```
String input = "Hello/World";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<!\\\\)[/=]");
```

The above single regex covers both splitting cases.  It uses a negative lookbehind, which asserts that the character which immediately precedes the `/` or `=` is *not* a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\\\\)` to assert what is on the left is not a backslash.

Then match 1+ times a forward slash or an equals sign `[/=]+` using a character class:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\\\)[/=]+";
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/vgGDm3) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mLvEhN/1)